# Scope in structs c++

Tags: c++, scope

I'm using C++ to make a program that fills a Deck struct with cards. Here is the Deck definition:

```
struct Deck{
    char suit;
    int value;
};
```

My problem is that the function using my struct, `fillDeck`, is not able to access the contents of the struct. Maybe I'm doing it completely wrong, but here is what I have:

```
void fillDeck(Deck *deck){
   for (int num  = 2; num <= 14; num++){
   for(int count = 0; count < 4; count++){
         if(count == 0){
            suit = "clubs";
         }
         if(count == 1){
            suit = "hearts";
         }
         if(count == 2){
             suit = "diamonds";
         }
         if(count == 3){
             suit = "spades";
         }
    }
   }
}
```

My main function is as follows.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
   Deck deck;
   fillDeck(&deck);
}
```

Comment: I apologize for code being slightly weird to read. Stack Overflow wouldn't let me post the question unless I formatted it that way. Things look a little too spaced apart to me. More so than normal.

Comment: You are treating `suit` as a variable by itself, you need to access through `deck.suit`.

Comment: Also I think it should be some like :  char * suit

Comment: when i use your method of deck.suit it gives me the error:
"request for member "suit" in "deck" which is of pointer type "Deck*" (maybe you meant to use ->)"
I dont know where i would use that though.

Comment: "...that fills a Deck struct with cards" There's a problem, your struct only has space for one card. Also `suit` should be an `enum`, so you don't have to compare strings, and you should pass the `deck` by *reference*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main function will work if you change your struct member `suit` to a string.

```
#include <string>

struct Deck
{
    std::string suit;
    int value;
};
```

And then access it in `fillDeck` like so:

```
...
deck->suit = "clubs";
...
```

Comment: @James Please accept the post as answer if it works well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your struct like this

```
struct Deck{
    char* suit;
    int value;
};
```

Then you can access it like this:

```
deck->suit
```

Comment: It gave me the error:
"warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to char*"
Im sorry if I seem to have simple problems with easy solutions, I'm very new to c++

Comment: Using either `->` or `.` depends on how the item was defined. The deck in main would use `deck.suit` while using a pointer it's `deck->suit`. In the OP case for inside the function it's `->`.

Comment: @James Make it `const char*`. String literals like `"example"` are constant.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek but can he store a string in char suit?

Comment: when I used the `const char` method it compiled. I really appreciate all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

Using std::string is a good option if you need to keep the full name of the suits.
If you have to use character for suits then you may use abbreviation as follows:

```
void fillDeck(Deck *deck){
   for (int num  = 2; num <= 14; num++){
   for(int count = 0; count < 4; count++){
         if(count == 0){
            deck->suit = `C`;
         }
         if(count == 1){
            deck->suit = `H`;
         }
         if(count == 2){
             deck->suit = `D`;
         }
         if(count == 3){
             deck->suit = `S`;
         }
    }
   }
}
```

The you can adjust the rest of your accordingly.

Also instead of the consecutive if statements you may want to try `switch case` statement, which may look better in that case.

Answer (score 0):

In looking at what you're passing to the fillDeck(Deck *deck) function inside of your main(), I would say that you are probably passing your deck argument wrong as right now you are passing the address to a Deck data structure that you have yet to initialize...

I think the  strategy you should take is to define a pointer of type Deck inside of your main function, maybe something like Deck *ptrDeck, and that pointer should then be pointed to an new struct of type Data. I do not really understand your problem set too well right now, but I would also think that maybe that pointer should really be pointing to an Array of type deck that will then hold each suit with its corresponding value. You will most likely have to populate said Array of type Data using a for loop to hold each suit and value. this can/should be done in its own function.

you can then create another function that would print each initialized instance of your Deck struct.

your for loop will probably have something like ptrDeck[i].suit = "whatever it is"...but then again you have your suits declared as type char so it seems to me that maybe you have to think this through a little...

im no expert, It took me a while to understand pointers and how to access data inside of a struct. but i recognize the difficulty you are having as it is similar to what i had and this is just the process i would go through to solve it without explicitly writing out the code for you...

if my understanding of this is off somewhere someone please let me know, it would be cool to get some feedback...

Comment: I was actually having a problem with figuring out how i would make sure my struct is being populated so I think youre right in thinking i need an array instead of just a struct. I need what you said explained to me in other terms though so im going to link you to my other question on this exact topic
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637856/print-contents-of-struct

Comment: you need an array AND your struct. it is an array of type struct that your pointer points to